# How to detect when Xamarin.Forms app is running in App Center?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center-test

I have a Xamarin Forms app, with tests using Xamarin.UITest, and I need to detect when it's running in App Center Test.

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/environment-variables), an environment variable `RUNNING_IN_APP_CENTER` should be set to `1` automatically - but `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RUNNING_IN_APP_CENTER")` doesn't have a value at runtime.

Indeed, if I loop over all environment variables, it's not there:

```
KNOX_STORAGE:/data/knox/ext_sdcard
ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote:11
ASEC_MOUNTPOINT:/mnt/asec
MONO_DEBUG:gen-compact-seq-points
TMPDIR:/data/user/0/com.acme.widgets.dev/cache
XA_HTTP_CLIENT_HANDLER_TYPE:Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler
PATH:/sbin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/odm/bin:/vendor/bin:/vendor/xbin
MC_AUTH_TOKEN_PATH:/efs
XDG_CONFIG_HOME:/data/user/0/com.acme.widgets.dev/files/.config
DOWNLOAD_CACHE:/data/cache
ANDROID_ASSETS:/system/app
XA_TLS_PROVIDER:btls
ANDROID_ROOT:/system
MONO_GC_PARAMS:major=marksweep
XAMARIN_BUILD_ID:4658cc0f-1a7c-4c97-93a6-f2f09c5edb04
BOOTCLASSPATH:/system/framework/core-oj.jar:/system/framework/core-libart.jar:/system/framework/conscrypt.jar:/system/framework/okhttp.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/sprengine.jar:/system/framework/android.hidl.base-V1.0-java.jar:/system/framework/android.hidl.manager-V1.0-java.jar:/system/framework/knoxsdk.jar:/system/framework/timakeystore.jar:/system/framework/fipstimakeystore.jar:/system/framework/sec_edm.jar:/system/framework/knoxanalyticssdk.jar:/system/framework/smartbondingservice.jar:/system/framework/ucmopensslenginehelper.jar:/system/framework/esecomm.jar:/system/framework/securetimersdk.jar:/system/framework/sec_sdp_sdk.jar:/system/framework/sec_sdp_hidden_sdk.jar:/system/framework/framework-oahl-backward-compatibility.jar:/system/framework/android.test.base.jar:/system/framework/knoxvpnuidtag.jar:/system/framework/SemAudioThumbnail.jar:/system/framework/knoxguard.jar:/system/framework/drutils.jar
ANDROID_DATA:/data
LANG:en-GB
EXTERNAL_STORAGE:/sdcard
ANDROID_BOOTLOGO:1
ENC_EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET:/storage/enc_emulated
HOME:/data/user/0/com.acme.widgets.dev/files
SYSTEMSERVERCLASSPATH:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/ethernet-service.jar:/system/framework/wifi-service.jar:/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar:/system/framework/hqm.jar:/system/framework/hcm.jar
ANDROID_STORAGE:/storage
XDG_DATA_HOME:/data/user/0/com.acme.widgets.dev/files/.local/share
```

I've also tried altering my App Center CLI command to include extra environment variables, as per the docs:

```sh
--test-parameter "app_env=MY_VAR=1"
```

But just the same, the `MY_VAR` is not available in the app.

Is there some other way to read environment variables that I'm missing, or perhaps some other way to detect when running in App Center Test?

Comment: Did you run the UITest on App Center ? Maybe you can check https://tomsoderling.github.io/AppCenter-Automated-UI-tests-on-build/ .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Yes, I'm using Xamarin.UITest (updated the Q to include this). I do eventually plan to start test runs from Azure DevOps, but for now I'm using the App Center CLI locally.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the "Test Compiler Directive" to detect that in code:

```
#if ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD
    Xamarin.Calabash.Start(); 
    App.IsRunningInTestMode=true;
#endif
```

Look into your AppDelegate and MainActivity where you are enabling the Test configuration.

Comment: I *could* use a preprocessor directive, but I was hoping to detect at runtime instead. The docs say newer versions of VS enable this directive, but I use Rider. Furthermore, RELEASE builds don't add this directive, but DEBUG builds use a shared mono runtime (for faster local dev) - which App Center won't accept!

Comment: (cont) So basically if use a directive, I may as well add my own one; a valid approach, but annoying in such a large project that already has a huge matrix of projects/configurations